# How to change the data in Home component on the basis of menu component in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have three component namely App, Home and Menu. App is parent of Home and Menu. Home and Menu are siblings.

Menu component have some buttons, when user click on those buttons I want to change the state data of Home component. How to achieve this in React.js ?

App.js

```
function App() {
    const [isMenu, setIsMenu] = useState(false);
    let history = useHistory();
    const changeIsMenu = () => {
        setIsMenu(true);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <Header id="myHeader"></Header>
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <div className="menu-other">
                    <Router>
                        {isMenu && <Menu></Menu>}
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/"
                                render={(props) => <Login history={history} 
                                 changeIsMenu={changeIsMenu} {...props} />}
                            />
                            <Route exact path="/signup"
                                render={(props) => <Signup history={history} 
                                 changeIsMenu={changeIsMenu} {...props} />}
                            />
                           <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}> 
                           </Route>
                           <Route exact path="/create" component={Create}> 
                           </Route>
                           <Route exact path="/about" component={About}> 
                           </Route>
                        </Switch>
                    </Router>
                 </div>
              </Provider>
         </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Menu.js

```
class Menu extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.changeShow=this.changeShow.bind(this);
    }

    changeShow(option,event)
    {
        //I want to call a function of Home Component here
    }

    render(){
        //here I capture the event and call the changeShow() function
    }
}
```

Home.js

```
class Home extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("in constructor props =", this.props.mainData);
    this.state = {
        data: null,
        isFetch: false,
        clickEvent: false
    }
    this.allDataShow = this.allDataShow.bind(this);
    this.upcomingShow =  this.upcomingShow.bind(this);
}

allDataShow(){
    allData(this.props.mainData);
}

upcomingShow(){
    upcoming(this.props.mainData);
}


//I want to call this function from Menu component which is responsible to 
//change the state data of Home Component 
changeData(option) {
    console.log("I'm home changeData");
    switch (option) {
        case "All":
            console.log("All");
            this.allDataShow();
            break;

        case "Upcoming":
            console.log("Upcoming");
            this.upcomingShow();
            break;

        case "Today":
            console.log("Today");
            todayData();
            break;

        case "Next 7 days":
            console.log("Next 7 days");
            next7Days();
            break;

        case "GoTo Date":
            console.log("GoTo Date");
            gotoDate();
            break;

        case "Search":
            console.log("Search");
            search();
            break;

        case "Filter":
            console.log("Filter");
            break;

        case "Notify me":
            console.log("Notify me");
            break;

        default:
            console.log("default is here");
    }

}
render(){
    //here I display the state of Home Component
}
}
```

This is the code. I want to call a showData function of Home component from Menu component which is responsible to change the state data of Home component.

Comment: You need to store the state in `App`. Pass the values in the props to `Home` and pass a callback function as a prop to `Menu`.  Read the docs on [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: 1. Take a state var in the App component as isMenuButtonClicked=false and pass this flag to Home component 2. Now Make a function in the App component and pass it to Menu component  3. Call this function in the menu component when the buttons are clicked 4. In this function do code to change isMenuButtonClicked to true. 5. This way you can know the Menu buttons are clicked and can perform the changes in the Home component accordingly. By the way, the Ideal solution is to use Redux here but that's a big story you need to learn.

Comment: Either initialize the state on App component and pass it as prop to Home and Menu or use a state management library.

Comment: Rajat, I have provided the answer. Please see, It may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending `changeIsMenu` a prop to both components inside the render method, so the only thing you need now is to use this function inside your component using its props:

```
changeShow(option,event)
{

  //I want to call a function of Home Component here
  this.props.changeIsMenu()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using your **example** as so many other things also there, so making it very straightforward with basic `code`. Please bear with me I have used the `function component` in the example. You can do the same in `Class based component`.

[**Stackblitz link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-ua47cz?file=index.js)

> Explaination: I passed `flag` to **Home Component**, and a `setFlag` to **Menu Component**. In **Menu Component** calling `setFlag` on button click t.

**App.js**

```
const BasicExample = () => {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Menu setFlag={value => setFlag(value)} />

        <hr />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={props => <Home flag={flag} {...props} />}
        />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**Menu.js**

```
const Menu = ({ setFlag }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Click" onClick={() => setFlag(true)} />
  </div>
);

export default Menu;
```

**Home.js**

```
const Home = ({ flag }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    {flag ? "Menu button is clicked" : "Menu button is not clicked"}
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```